# Confused about jq parser

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm trying to use [jq parser](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) in my bash scripts and I'm confused about how it works, could someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Here is the original file from the external service and I need to get `value` from it:

```
root@test ~ # cat test.json 
{"sensors":[{"id":34585,"value":-3.06,"time":1457031003}]}
```

Trying to send it to `jq`:

```
root@test ~ # cat narod.json | jq
{
  "sensors": [
    {
      "id": 34585,
      "value": -3.06,
      "time": 1457031003
    }
  ]
}
```

Trying to get `sensors`:

```
root@test ~ # cat narod.json | jq '.sensors'
[
  {
    "id": 34585,
    "value": -3.06,
    "time": 1457031003
  }
]
```

Trying to get `value` from `sensors`:

```
root@test ~ # cat narod.json | jq '.sensors.value'
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot index array with string "value"
```

Comment: Try `jq sensors[].value` not at my computer so can't test or post a full answer but will do later

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot and could you explain or give me a link where I was wrong?

Comment: `.sensors` in your JSON input is an _array_, not a dict. It doesn't _have_ indexes like .value – only its inner items do. So you need to tell jq to apply the index to each item of the array using `[]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, in this specific case you should use:

```
jq sensors[].value
```

This is because you need to tell `jq` to expect an array (denoted by the `[` `]`). Effectively this is saying, 'search at the next level down in the hierarchy.'

In general, when you encounter an array (`[`) in your json file you should provide this in your query: `jq array_name[].object_in_array` would return the contents of `object_in_array`.

Answer (score 1):

Something to keep in mind when working with arrays in [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is that the [[]](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.[]) operator will enumerate each of the array's values, so

```
 .sensors[].value
```

returns the `.value` of all objects in `.sensors`.  It is equivalent to the filter

```
   .["sensors"]    # choose value of "sensors" key
 | .[]             # enumerate each value
 | .["value"]      # choose value of "value" key
```

should you want the `.value` for a particular object often you'll want to include a [select](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)).  e.g.

```
 .sensors[] | select(.id == 34585) | .value
```